# Need a choke coil inductor for DC welder

Tags: dc

Working on making an AC 225 volt welder into an AC/DC welder (225 volt AC and 125 volt DC).  I purchased bridge rectifier for 225 amp and 220 volts.  I am going to use two 3500 uF capacitors and a choke coil on the DC side.  I need to build a choke coil inductor to filter out high AC signals for it now.  Any ideas on how to construct this?

Can I use an iron core with nbr 4 insulated wire wrapped around it ?

Comment: Choke for filtering out 50/60 Hz? Err... You might be able to attenuate the AC component with a humongous large choke. I sense XY problem.

Comment: One needs to know V, ESR or peak Amp to determine saturation , L/C ratio and fo , ripple current depends on total ReqC>>f

Comment: here is a link to an AC to DC conversion project ... http://www.hildstrom.com/projects/ac-225/  ... he used 5 turns of 2 AWG on microwave transformer core

Comment: Why are you trying to do this conversion?